# Find a manifold which contains embedding of $K_5$

Tags: graph-theory, differential-topology

$K_5$ graph is not planar .
I was asked to find a manifold which contains embedding of $K_5$ and use $5$ squares to represent $K_5$ "on" my new manifold.

Embedding means that it can be drawn on the manifold in such a way that its edges intersect only at their endpoints. In other words, it can be drawn in such a way that no edges cross.

I can find embedding of $K_5$ in Three-dimensional space but this is not a $5$ squares representation ..

I don't know what I am looking for,  so I'd be glad if anyone could help.

p.s
This is my first question here so please be patient

thanks, bar

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "square" in the context of a manifold.

Comment: I know , It's not clear to me too
I try to figure it out right now

Comment: BTW it was not necessary to post a new question, you could have edited the [original one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412187/find-embedding-for-k5-with-five-squares). Or you could have at least deleted the older question, otherwise we would have here duplicate questions. (As I see, your original post has been deleted by a moderator.)

Answer (score 4):

$K_5$ can be [embedded](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/GraphTheory/MyGraphTheory/embedding.htm) into a torus.

Comment: but what with the "5 squares representation" requirement ? and can you detail how to do it?

Comment: The embedding is given in the link I provided.  I have no idea what a "5 squares representation" is; perhaps your course notes have some clue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can only guess what "5 squares representation" means, but this is an embedding of $K_5$ into a [torus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus) where several squares are kind of "visible" (although they are not faces of this [toroidal embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_graph) of $K_5$ - I am not sure what is the correct English terminology for this).

[image]

(I have made a picture using metapost. It is figure 5 in the metapost source code, which I have put in pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/7vKvRCt9).)

You can probably find many ways how K5 can be embedded into toroid if you simply google for
[k5 toroid](http://images.google.com/images?q=torus+k5). You might have a look of some of these embeddings - it might help your intuition about this problem and maybe you will something which is interesting for you in the connection with the problem you are trying to solve.)

EDIT: My original picture contained some edges which were not supposed to be there, so I have replaced it with a new one.

Comment: You're welcome. As I said, I do not know what *representation using 5 squares* means. Have you looked at the google search (see the link in my post)? On of the pictures illustrating embedding of $K_5$ given there consists only of squares, see [here](http://www.combinatorialmath.ca/G&G/G/K5_1.gif). (I have to admit that simply putting question into Google feels a little like cheating, but since the question was somewhat unclear and I did not have a better idea, that is what I have tried.)

Comment: I looked at the google search and I noticed this picture too  : [link](http://www.combinatorialmath.ca/G&G/G/K5_2.gifsearch ) I must to admit that i'm not really sure i understand the difference between them and how i get it if my start point is the K5 on the planar. but might be i should google it and try harder to understand it